# Abreviar label dos nomes dos dias da semana

Tags: angular

Versões

Angular:
`"@angular/core": "11.2.1"`

Syncfusion:
`"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule": "^19.1.65"`

---

Estou utilizando o [schedule do syncfusion](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/schedule/overview) e ao fazer a globalização percebi que ao abrir o calendario os nomes dos dias da semana estao por extenso, o que acaba fazendo com que um fique em cima do outro, portanto, gostaria de abreviar eles...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso dos dias da semana, na propria agenda (Qua 02, Qui 03, Sex 04, ...) eu fiz desta forma com o `ng-template`:

```
<ejs-schedule #scheduleObj height="1000px" [views]='views' locale="pt-PT" [eventSettings]="eventSettings"
    (eventRendered)="eventRendered($event)">
    <ng-template #dateHeaderTemplate let-data>
        <div class="e-header-day">{{getDateHeaderWeekDay(data.date)}}</div>
        <div class="e-header-date">{{getDateHeaderDay(data.date)}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</ejs-schedule>
```

Essa função `getDateHeaderWeekDay()` retorna o nome abreviado...

Eu tentei fazer desta forma, mas nao funcionou:

```
<ng-template #weekHeaderTemplate>
    <div>Dom</div>
    <div>Seg</div>
    <div>Ter</div>
    <div>Qua</div>
    <div>Qui</div>
    <div>Sex</div>
    <div>Sab</div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Portuguese culture ‘pt-PT’ returns the entire day name for abbreviated format from the CLDR data due to that the misalignment occurs.

**Solution1:**
You can overcome this using below CSS.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ej2-angular-schedule-pt-pt-culture?file=app.component.ts

```
  .e-calendar .e-content th {
    width: 25px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

**Solution 2:**
You can use ‘pt’ locale instead of ‘pt-PT’ which shows the short name of the day as per your requirement, please refer to the following sample.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ej2-angular-schedule-portuguese-culture?file=app.component.ts

Comment: I used the solution 2 and it works, thanks